How to resolve tough-cookie 4.1.3 vulnerable issue in angular 16
I am getting below the vulnerable issue in my angular version 16 application. How to resolve this issue. If anyone know the answer please help to find the solution.

Versions of the package tough-cookie before 4.1.3 are vulnerable to Prototype Pollution due to improper handling of Cookies when using CookieJar in rejectPublicSuffixes=false mode. This issue arises from the manner in which the objects are initialized.

image here
File path: raz_25896.tgz#/raz_25896/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie
